# Selecting and extending multiple image durations simultaneously

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

So, I'm not sure I'm even doing this the right way or not but I've got a video and I'm overlaying that with multiple images (up to 20 some in some area's) which pretty much stay on screen throughout the whole video, but alter at certain points, changing places, sizes and rotations etc.

Some of these don't alter and I've grouped those up into compound clips, but the vast majority all remain free, which is a massive pain in the backside when I progress a few minutes through the footage and then need to drag the end duration point of fourteen or fifteen images up to bring everything back onto the screen to see if everything is aligned!

Is there a way to select multiple images and drag the end point of them all together?  I've googled this and can't find anything that works at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the images - use the select tool (`A`) to rubber-band them - and hit `Control-D`. Amend the duration and it'll be applied to all the selected images.

Comment: awesome thanks for this! you've saved me years! 

Comment: no probs - shame it's been a month since the original post!